# How to input in console while running Qt Application in python?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt4

I can't input anything from the user in the terminal while running a PyQt Application.

Actually i am creating something but i can't show the whole code here so there is the **main** of the code, and believe that i need the fix of it only:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    btn = QPushButton()
    btn.setText("Input In Console")
    box = QFormLayout()
    box.addRow(btn)
    btn.clicked.connect(input_txt)
    window.setLayout(box)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def input_txt():
    input("Enter you Name ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window()
```

And while running as i press the button a disaster of loop starts:
[image: The Result of It]

I really tried a  lot configuring the solution of this problem but all failed. Hope these information helped, if any question regarding the post then please say in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't need this anymore but still i am posting answer for if someone else having problem with the same.

**Solution** : Use Threads

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys,threading
def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    btn = QPushButton()
    btn.setText("Input In Console")
    box = QFormLayout()
    box.addRow(btn)
    btn.clicked.connect(input_txt)
    window.setLayout(box)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def input_txt():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=input)
    thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window()
```